# LibGdx weird texture behaviour

Tags: java, opengl, graphics, libgdx, textures

So I am trying to render a sprite with this texture:

[image: How it is supposed to look]

However, it renders like this:

[image: How it actually looks]

In the original texture, every line has a width of 1px. In the rendered texture,the top line seems to have dissapeared from the top and moved to the bottom effectively forming a 2px line. The texture is loaded from a single file, not a sheet.

I have disabled/enabled texture filtering, it did not help.

I have made sure the camera is not zoomed in or out.

I have made sure the texture is not scaled in any way.

I haven't specified any wrap for the texture.

Any ideas as to what may be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!

Seems that this occurs when trying to draw the texture at position with decimals (in my case it was x=580.5), to fix it I had to use Math.round() to ensure that it was a full number.

I thought that LibGdx and/or opengl was capable of rendering with subpixel precision. Weird.